# What are the dependencies for a certain wheel (.whl) package?

Tags: python

I would like to install pylab and I don't have a direct access to pip (proxy limitations). I cannot make it through cntlm or other proxy tunneling solutions.

So I have two solutions:

1. install each package manually, run it, install the missing dependency and go back to (1)
2. download the wheel and fetch the dependencies list.

I don't know how to do (2).

Is there any easy way to list the required wheel files to install another wheel file?

There are many related questions to "how to use pip offline", but I still did not find happiness there.

```
$ pip install pylab-0.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./pylab-0.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting networkx (from pylab==0.1.3)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(2, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))': /simple/networkx/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(2, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))': /simple/networkx/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Short incomplete description)

To find the dependencies of the whl:

- Change the filename extension from whl to zip
- unzip
- open the metadata or metadata.json file in the folder ending with .dist-info
- if it's a normal text file - look for the lines beginning with `Requires-Dist:` - if it's a json file look for the `requires` array - and parse out these contents.

Comment: (would be good with a script that does this - but haven't found time to create that yet)